# Bourbon whiskey, Bourbon monarchy: is there a connection?

Tags: etymology

Is there any connection between *bourbon*, the name of the American whiskey, and *Bourbon*, the French monarchy, or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbon_%28whiskey%29) claims the name comes from Bourbon County, Kentucky.

So yes and no, because Bourbon County does get its name from the French Monarchy (see Paris, Kentucky)